# iOS App/Service Restrictions

Tags: ios

This question is speaking in more general terms rather than a specific issue, but is it possible for an App to have the ability to activate and deactivate service? I know it would take cooperation from the carrier, but in theory could you have an app that essentially controls your ability to turn your service off and on? I realize there are apps that block certain features like internet access, but I'm talking about completely cutting the phones service or reactivating it all together. Is this something that could be done, or is iOS to sandboxed to allow for such access?

Comment: Apps that can block internet access? On an un-jail-broken device?

Comment: @ShamasS I guess in that regard I am thinking of a jailbroken device.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be a jail-broken device, otherwise Apple is really uptight about sandboxing the applications.